# Lauch function with arguments as a thread in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, python-multithreading

Im trying to lauch this programm as a infinite thread in my program
https://github.com/qLethon/bitmex_simple_websocket

```
from bitmex_simple_websocket import BitMEXWebSocket
import json

class MyBitMEXWebsocket(BitMEXWebSocket):
    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        data = json.loads(message)
        if 'table' in data and data['table'] == 'tradeBin1m':
            print(data['data'][0])

bitmex = MyBitMEXWebsocket(endpoint='wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=tradeBin1m:XBTUSD')
```

how launch it in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

as a thread correctly

---

In my current code, only first thread **myBitMEXWebsocket** function starts, but **tradingview** and **trader** wont

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
                Thread(target = MyBitMEXWebsocket(endpoint='wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=quote:XBTUSD')).start()
                Thread(target = tradingview).start()  
                for count_var_short, count_var_long in tradingview():
                        trader(count_var_short,count_var_long)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved, i asked github author, he gives this answer

```
class MyBitMEXWebsocket(BitMEXWebSocket):
    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        data = json.loads(message)
        if 'table' in data and data['table'] == 'quote':
                print(data['data'][0])
                WS_BestBid = (data['data'][0]["bidPrice"])
                WS_BestAsk = (data['data'][0]["askPrice"])
                        #print('bid:',WS_BestBid)
                        #print('ask:',WS_BestAsk)
                        #print('bid:',data['data'][0]["bidPrice"])
                        #print('ask:',data['data'][0]["askPrice"])
def f():

        MyBitMEXWebsocket(endpoint='wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=quote:XBTUSD,order:XBTUSD') 
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=f)
        th1.start() 

if __name__ == '__main__':

            Thread(target = f).start()  
            Thread(target = tradingview).start()  
            for count_var_short, count_var_long in tradingview():
                    trader(count_var_short,count_var_long)
```